pyrcc_main.py: File does not exist 'resources.qrc'
pyrcc_main.py: File does not exist 'resources.qrc'
build yolo environment
error： (yolo) D:\1download\yolov5_master\tools\labelImg-master\labelImg-master>python labelimg.py
python: can't open file 'labelimg.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
